# Querying the attribute of first child of an xml element using xPath

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I'm having the following small snippet:

```
[xml]$doc = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://www.jetbrains.com/updates/updates.xml")

$xPath = "//product[@name='IntelliJ IDEA']//channel[@id='IC-IU-RELEASE-licensing-RELEASE']//[1]"
$node = $doc | Select-XML -XPath $xPath
```

The idea is to get the latest build version for IntelliJ using the above xPath. I am interested in the line

```xml
<build number="222.4345" version="2022.2.3" releaseDate="20220726" fullNumber="222.4345.14">
```

and want to extract the version attribute.

Using the above xPath `//product[@name='IntelliJ IDEA']//channel[@id='IC-IU-RELEASE-licensing-RELEASE']//[1]` I am getting back all builds.

Switching to `//product[@name='IntelliJ IDEA']//channel[@id='IC-IU-RELEASE-licensing-RELEASE']//build[1]` I indeed getting the first build, but without the actual build node, which would yield the version attribute.

If I want to simply iterate over all versions using `$doc | Select-XML -XPath $xPath | ForEach-Object { $_.Node.version }`  I am getting an empty result back. My mistake must be something trivial, but I am at a total loss.

What is the correct syntax for getting the first build node here?

Comment: `$firstVersion = $doc |Select-Xml -XPath "//product[@name='IntelliJ IDEA']/channel[@id='IC-IU-RELEASE-licensing-RELEASE']/build[@version][1]"|% Node|% Version`

Comment: Would you mind adding this as an answer with a short explanation, what `/build[@version][1]"|% Node|% Version` actually does, so I dont simply copy something I dont fully understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a single `/` to describe the immediate child nodes, not `//`.

Using `./build[1]` to get the first `<build />` node under a given parent is correct, but if you want to make sure you pick the first one *that has a `version` attribute*, do `./build[@version][1]`:

```
$firstVersion = $doc |Select-Xml -XPath "//product[@name='IntelliJ IDEA']/channel[@id='IC-IU-RELEASE-licensing-RELEASE']/build[@version][1]" |% Node |% Version
```